# libgdx resolution/density scaling assets

Tags: libgdx, screen, resolution, scaling

Quick question,

I am working on a game in libgdx and have hit a snag. I'm trying to scale my assets and I'm using `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()` to get the density and then setting my asset size using that as a multiplier. The issue I'm having is that on a tablet that has a `2560x1600` resolution has a density of 2.0, yet the nexus 5 emulator that has `1080x1920` has a density of 2.652... how does the tablet have a smaller density then the smaller phone?

What should I be using to get my multiplier for scaling if density is not reliable based on the android app screen size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your first question, it's a hardware thing. The Nexus 5 probably has a higher PPI (pixels per inch) ratio than the second, even though the resolution is smaller.

As to your second question, I would propose an alternative to `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()`: If you are trying to make sure that your asset is the same size relative to the screen (i.e. a 80x80 asset on a 2560x1600 display would be half the size on a 1280x800 display), then I think you want to leave your assets the same size and *change the size of your camera instead*.

When you create a game in libGDX (or any game engine), you need to keep in mind the difference between three sets of sizes/coordinates in your game:

- **Viewport** size is the size of the space on your screen where your game will draw. It is measured in pixels and defaults to your window size (in a fullscreen game, the size of the screen).
- **game world** size/coordinates are completely arbitrary. They are measured in whatever unit you want (be it meters, inches, bananas, F16s, etc.). You'll know you're working in game world units because you have floats.
- **camera** size is the amount 'world' you can see at one time measured in game units. You can make your camera show a 1280x800 portion of the world or a 3x5 portion of the world or a 137.6x42 portion. The tricky thing is that libGDX's OrthographicCamera class defaults your viewport size, acting as though 1 game unit == 1 pixel.

Hopefully that made sense. Let's look at the implications:

Say I have a 800x600 GU (game unit) asset at 0,0 in my game world. My viewport size is 2560x1600, and my camera is scaled to 2560x1600 as well. My 800x600 GU object will render a 800x600 px image on the screen.

Now suppose I want to port my game to other screen sizes with the same ratio (just to keep things simple for now). I still have a 2560x1600 viewport size, but I change my camera to 8x5 GU and my game object to 2.5x1.875 GU. These sizes will be set explicitely- independent of the viewport size. This makes 1 GU = 320px. The net result is that my game object will still render a 800x600px image on the screen.

Now let's see how this would work on a 1280x800px resolution: My viewport is 1280x800 px, but my camera stays at 8x5 GU and my game object at 2.5x1.875 GU. Because of the size of the camera, 1 GU = 160px, which means my game object renders at 400x300, which means it is proportionally the same size on the smaller screen.

Hopefully that made sense without pictures. When you start using screens with different aspect ratios (i.e. you go from an 8x5 screen to a 3x2 screen), you need a little extra logic to keep the aspect ratio of your viewport the same as your camera (otherwise things get all stretched). Fortunately, libGDX provides [some viewports which will do this for you](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/package-summary.html).

You can find an [external tutorial](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/) by the libGDX community here that talks more about this issue.

Comment: Actually incredibly informative! I have tried to use viewports and cameras, just never got them working correctly. Let me ask a stupid question, my game is a puzzle like game that has no screen movement, so the camera would always stay in the same location... all I really need to happen is on tablets my assets increase by say x2 and on a small screens the assets would scale on a x.75 I just want the images to look the same on bigger screens they are high enough quality that they scale fine. Im just not sure what the best way to go about something that simple would be? I keep hitting a wall.

Comment: Honestly, I would still use a camera once you consider more than one resolution. While a lot of the benefits really come into play when you have moving parts (and what's to say you won't add 'effect' movements in the future?), it's still good practice. It's a little more complex the first time you do it, but it's actually not that hard to do.

Comment: Okay thanks so much! one last silly question... if I have tables that hold my assets such as imageButtons, buttons, checkboxes, etc. Taking the imageButton for an example how does the camera and viewport increase the tables size? or maybe a link on how to implement camera and viewport, because when I do it I can get my background the I am batch.draw (ing) but I cannot seem to get the viewport and camera to increase all the assets within tables etc?

Comment: Scene2D adds an additional layer of complexity in that it takes a viewport and manages the camera for you. It's a little weird at first, but you can have multiple viewports layered on top of each other (e.g. one for your game objects, one for your UI) and each will have a separate camera. This allows you to separate your UI from your game logic, which can be helpful if you want to use Scene2D.ui for your UI and then draw the rest of your game yourself without Scene2D.

Comment: oh wow! haha okay im definitely in over my head on this.. Thank you so much john! for the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks so much @John for this great explanation. That makes thins so much easier!

Comment: *To answer your first question, it's a hardware thing. The Nexus 5 probably has a higher PPI (pixels per inch) ratio than the second, even though the resolution is smaller.* How!? The resolutions are the pixels and if there are less pixels on a bigger screen then the density is lower. I'm also running into problems with `getDensity()` and trying to find alternatives to get text drawn at the same size on each device. Not in the same amount of pixels, but the same real world size.